# How to connect to a digitransit broker with a specific topic using paho mqtt client

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am pretty new to MQTT and I would like to establish a connection to a digitransit mqtt broker to receive public transportation data using python paho mqtt client. To connect to a broker the port and the topic is needed.

Regarding the information provided in the broker source I guess I need at least two pieces of information but I am not sure if something is missing. Please not that the script is executed via browser based jupyter notebook.

Broker source: https://digitransit.fi/en/developers/apis/4-realtime-api/vehicle-positions/
Paho documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/index.php

- Port: 8883
- Topic: /hfp/v2/journey/#
- Broker: mqtt.hsl.fi

When running via command line the data can be received, e.g.

```
/hfp/v2/journey/ongoing/vp/bus/0022/01281/1040/2/Elielinaukio/14:29/1140118/0//// {"VP":{"desi":"40","dir":"2","oper":22,"veh":1281,"tst":"2022-07-06T11:56:53.417Z","tsi":1657108613,"spd":null,"hdg":null,"lat":null,"long":null,"acc":null,"dl":-101,"odo":8530,"drst":0,"oday":"2022-07-06","jrn":2646,"line":62,"start":"14:29","loc":"ODO","stop":null,"route":"1040","occu":0}}
```

You can try this out simply using two commands:

```
npm install -g mqtt
```

```
mqtt subscribe -h mqtt.hsl.fi -p 8883 -l mqtts -v -t "/hfp/v2/journey/#"
```

When running on a jupyter notebook or python script I only see the output that is defined `on_connect`method but no data shows up.

My code snippet is:

```
# pip install paho-mqtt

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+ str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("/hfp/v2/journey/#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.tls_set()
client.connect("mqtt.hsl.fi", 8883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Does anyone know what kind of detail is wrong or missing?

UPDATE: The accepted solution works for python scripts executed via python IDE like Pycharm or Visual Studio Code but not with browser based IDEs like Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a detailed description of how the code you've shown doesn't work and include any output or error messages. At the moment the quesiton really isn't clear as to what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added some more information.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers (and impossible to search). Please post the text and format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have not told the Python Paho Client it needs to connect using TLS.

Add the `client.tls_set()` before the call to `connect()`

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.tls_set()
client.connect("mqtt.hsl.fi", 8883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Ah thanks I got one step forward. Now I am receiving the print output ```Connected with result code 0``` defined in the ```on_connect``` method but no data/message is printed what is defined in the ```on_message``` method.

Comment: Give it a moment, the response is not instant

Comment: Hmm I waited for 5 minutes and no data received so far... but the return code 0 indicates that the connection is successful.

Comment: The only change I made to the code you posted in the question was to add the `client.tls_set()` and it floods the terminal with messages.

Comment: I am using a jupyter notebook not a terminal. I also tried the port 443 (see broker source) but no data appearing so far.

Comment: If I try port 1883 the error log is ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory```.

Comment: The jupyter notebook is browser based. Probably thats the difference.